# in the selection mode "by pressing button b", how to deselect previous vertices?

Tags: selection-tools

I'm confused by the selection mode triggered by pressing the shortcut key "b".

In this mode, it by default keeps my previous selection, and when I select a new vertex, for example, for most of the time, this new selection will be added to my old selection. But for some other times, my new selection will deselect the previous selection, and becomes the only selected vertex.

I'm curious what alters this behavior. For most of the times, I want my new selection to deselect the old vertices. How do I do it?

Comment: There is Deselect option in User prefs for Border Select disabled by default, if it's enabled it will deselect anything before selecting. Note this behaviour is changed from 2.8+ as long as activating mode with B

Comment: I'm using 2.8 actually, I was describing the behavior I saw in 2.8

Answer (score 1):

When activating border select(b) middle mouse will deselect while left mouse will select.

-eh five

Comment: Just in case your curious, ctrl and left mouse button will activate lasso select.